# Cannot cast COM interface converted to VB.NET to a C++ equivalent

Tags: c++, vb.net, com

The old C++ error module implements one interface:

```
    [
        object,
        uuid(7286455D-A48B-11D1-8C7E-006097089085),
        dual,
        helpstring("IDQSEror Interface"),
        pointer_default(unique)
    ]
    interface IDQSEror : IDispatch
    {
        [id(1), helpstring("method getLastError")] HRESULT getLastError([out] BSTR 
                   ...
```

When everything was in C++ this interface could be passed between other COM modules without problem. However, we've converted a middle module to VB.NET and returning the IDQSEror required casting:

```
NAVInitServr (VB.NET COM)
  References
    MainModule.PIA (interop assembly #include IDQError)
    DQSError.PIA (interop assembly defines IDQError)
  NavInit.vb
   - Is called by MainModule
   - Creates a DQSEror class
   - Returns IDQSEror to the MainModule
   - Requires casting:  
      Dim error as DQSError = new DQSEror()
      return DirectCast(error, MainModule.PIA.IDQSerror)
```

Otherwise there is a casting error. We have rewritten DQSError in VB.NET:

```
     InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch) 
    Public Interface IDQSEror

    DispId(1)
    Sub getLastError()
    ...

    End Interface
```

The interface has the same GUID and DispId as the one in C++. The casting to return the error to the MainModule does not work anymore:

```
    Dim error as DQSError = new DQSEror()
return DirectCast(error, MainModule.PIA.IDQSerror)
```

Comment: Very unclear why a cast is needed at all.  Your VB.NET code should declare a class that implements IMyErrorModule and it must be `<ComVisible(true)>`.  No cast required.  Use less words, more code to explain your problem.

Comment: Solved it. The function called was declared "Public Function Init()  As MainModule.PIA.IDQSError", changed for "Public Function Init()  As DQSError.IDQSError". Now it works. Beats me why, cause this is exactly what I was asking to do with casting. Internal COM type war...